# Codeigniter Bootstrap Pagination (Page displays all data in same table)

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, pagination

Why i am getting all data in same page ?

The function is working as it displays the page (1,2,3) as number of data in database table . But displays the data all in one page .

**CONTROLLER PAGE of my application it calls the bootstrap pagination**

```
public function reportTransaction(){
    //pagination settings followed from that tutorial
    //base url defined application
    $config['base_url'] = site_url('inventory/reportTransaction'); 

    //code that gets rows from the transaction model
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->transactionLog->countAll();

    //defined per page as 5
    $config['per_page'] = 5; 

    $config["uri_segment"] = 3; 
    $choice = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
    $config["num_links"] = ceil($choice);

    //echo $config["num_links"];

   //config for bootstrap pagination class integration
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['first_link'] = false;
    $config['last_link'] = false;
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['page'] = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

    //call the model function to get the transaction data
    $data['posts'] = $this->transactionLog->get_report();           
    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    //print_r($data['posts']);
    //load the department_view
    $this->load->view('admin/reportTransaction', $data);
    $this->header();
    $this->footer();
}
```

MODEL that called in controller

```
function get_report($limit = null)
    {
        if ($limit != null) {
            $this->db->limit($limit['limit'], $limit['offset']);
        }

        $q = $this->db->query("SELECT `transaction`.`transaction_id`, ABS(`cost`) as cst,`transaction`.`date_posted`, ABS(`unit`) as unt, `detail`.`name` as sam, `product`.`productName` as pam, `transaction`.`type` FROM `transaction` INNER JOIN `detail` ON `detail`.`type`=`transaction`.`type` INNER JOIN `product` ON `product`.`product_id`=`transaction`.`product_id`");

//        $q = $this->db->get($this->table);

        if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($q->result() as $row)
            {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }

    function countAll()
    {
        return $this->db->count_all($this->table);
    }
```

VIEW Page of the application that displays the data from the controller !!
This is the table that displays the data in the same page

```
   <table class="table tablesorter table-bordered table-hover table-striped sortable">
             <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>S/B Name</th>
                    <th>Product Name</th>
                   <th>Unit</th>
                   <th>Date Posted</th>
                </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                <?php $i=1; foreach($posts as $post): ?>
                <tr <?=($i % 2 == 0) ? 'class="even"' : '' ?>>
                    <td><?=$post->sam?></td>
                    <td><?=$post->pam?></td>
                  <td><?=$post->unt?></td>
                   <td><?=$post->date_posted?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
             </tbody>
          </table>
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
              <p><?php echo $pagination; ?></p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

PROBLEM THAT arrived in the system
All the data are displayed in same page
Pagination page number increases according to data but data displayed in same table

Comment: show your `get_report()` method from `transactionLog` model. Perhaps limit issue there

Comment: Rejoanul I have added the get_report from transactionLog code ..

Comment: You can't get paginated results unless you pass a `limit` and `offset` into your model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your `get_report()` as following

```
public function get_report($segment,$per_page)
{
  $data = array();

    $q = $this->db->query('SELECT `transaction`.`transaction_id`, ABS(`cost`) as cst,`transaction`.`date_posted`, ABS(`unit`) as unt, `detail`.`name` as sam, `product`.`productName` as pam, `transaction`.`type` FROM `transaction` INNER JOIN `detail` ON `detail`.`type`=`transaction`.`type` INNER JOIN `product` ON `product`.`product_id`=`transaction`.`product_id` LIMIT '.$segment.', '.$per_page);

    if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        $data = $q->result_array()
    }
    return $data;
}
```

And now call this in controller with `LIMIT` parameter

```
$data['posts'] = $this->transactionLog->get_report($data['page'],$config['per_page']);
```

and check now

Comment: There is no variable used in SQL query named `reportTransaction`. so query & pagination is ok now. You have to find entire code where `reportTransaction` is